# Apache headers are printed on the webpage

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm pretty new with the .htacces file and for some reason this is printed on every webpage???

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 07 Apr 2016 06:36:09 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Content-Length: 0 Connection: close Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

I don't know why? If I delete the .htacces it does not show.
This is my .htacces file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Redirect /update /sdp/wcs.start.cls


Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule    ^sdp/callsystem/?$    /sdp/callsystem.csp    [NC,L]    # Handle language requests
RewriteRule    ^sdp/callsystem/([0-9]+)/?$    /sdp/callsystem.csp?TAA=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle language requests
RewriteRule    ^sdp/logout?$    /sdp/logout.csp    [NC,L]    # Handle logout requests
```

Comment: You cannot add comments at the end if a line in `.htaccess` style files. You have to place them on separate lines.

Comment: it did not make a difference :-(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your conditional is unbalanced:

You have to close that `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` statement again:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ....
</IfModule>
```

Or you simply remove that conditional completely. It does not really make any sense in a `.htaccess` style file anyway.

Comment: Hm, no idea then, nothing wrong with what you posted otherwise. What does your http servers error log file reveal?

Comment: only that my favicon does not excist and the refer

Comment: That is not the error log file, that is most likely the access log file.